# LoremPixel component always renders same image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

This is a `LoremPixel` component that I built:

```
export default function LoremPixel({ url = 'http://lorempixel.com', width = 200, height = 400, alt = 'Placeholder image' }) {
  const src = `${url}/${width}/${height}`;
  return (<img className={centerImage} src={src} alt={alt} />);
}

const { string, number, oneOf } = PropTypes;

LoremPixel.propTypes = {
  url: string,
  height: oneOf(string, number),
  width: oneOf(string, number),
  alt: string,
};
```

I am supposed to get a randomized image of width 200 and height 400 every single time but instead I always see the same image in all my `LoremPixel` components.

[image: Cute puppy lorempixel repeated image]

I call it in my component like:

```
  return (
    <Card containerStyle={containerStyle}>
      <CardHeader
        title={title}
        style={headerRootStyle}
        textStyle={cardHeaderTextStyle}
        titleStyle={titleStyle}
      />
      <span className={authorStyle}>{author}</span>
      <CardMedia>
        <LoremPixel width={200} height={100} />
      </CardMedia>
      <CardText style={textStyle}>
        <LoremIpsum />
      </CardText>
      <CardActions style={actionsStyle}>
        <FlatButton label="Buy Now" />
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
```

from the `Book` component which is called in a `Bookshelf` component:

```
Books = books.map(book => (<div
  key={uuid.v4()}
  className={colFixedWidth}
  {...firstChild}
  {...secondChild}
>
  <Book {...book} />
</div>),
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you get the same image because of cache. You can add current timestamp to the url to avoid that:

```
const src = `${url}/${width}/${height}?t=${Date.now()}`;
```